# Failed to send messages with sms manager on API higher than 21

Tags: android

When i send message with sms manager on API 21 and lower it's  sent successfully but when i try to send it on API higher than 21 it doesn't appear in my sent messages, note (permission is granted).

Comment: Could you post the code you have related to message sending? also could you please any error you have in your stack trace?

Comment: Is there a snippet of code of where this occurs?

Comment: i think the error happens  when i try to send message in dual mobile sim-card 
this is my code :
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

Answer (score -1):

For API level higher than 19 you should use **Telephony** instead of **SmsManager**.
Here's [a link](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-telephony-manager-tutorial)